# Escape chroma key color

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to use the Sceneform framework from ARCore to play a video, based on the chromakeyVideo example project.

While creating the model:

```
 ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, R.raw.chroma_key_video)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(
            renderable -> {
              videoRenderable = renderable;
              renderable.getMaterial().setExternalTexture("videoTexture", texture);
              renderable.getMaterial().setFloat4("keyColor", CHROMA_KEY_COLOR);
            })
        .exceptionally(
            throwable -> {
              Toast toast =
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load video renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
              toast.show();
              return null;
            });
```

The code sets the keycolor to delete from the rendering (green, in this case), but I don't want any color to be removed from my render.
This is the line that sets that property:

```
renderable.getMaterial().setFloat4("keyColor", CHROMA_KEY_COLOR);
```

If I comment the line or replace the color with null, the color that is deleted is black. I don't see how to skip this process, and the documentation I found for the [setFloat4](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/Material#setFloat4(java.lang.String,%20com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Color)) is incomplete.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to create a new custom material that just uses the external texture vs. making the chromakeying optional.  You can create a new .mat file in the sampledata/models directory named `externalTexture.mat`:

```
// Copyright 2018 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
material {
    "name" : "Chroma Key Video Material",
    "defines" : [
        "baseColor"
    ],
    "parameters" : [
        {
           // The texture displaying the frames of the video.
           "type" : "samplerExternal",
           "name" : "videoTexture"
        }
    ],
    "requires" : [
        "position",
        "uv0"
    ],
    "shadingModel" : "unlit",
    // Blending is "masked" instead of "transparent" so that the shadows account for the
    // transparent regions of the video instead of just the shape of the mesh.
    "blending" : "masked",
    // Material is double sided so that the video is visible when walking behind it.
    "doubleSided" : true
}

fragment {
    void material(inout MaterialInputs material) {
        prepareMaterial(material);

        vec2 uv = getUV0();

        if (!gl_FrontFacing) {
          uv.x = 1.0 - uv.x;
        }

        material.baseColor = texture(materialParams_videoTexture, uv).rgba;
    }
}
```

Then in your .sfa file change the material source to externalTexture.mat:

```
     source: "sampledata/models/externalTexture.mat",
```

Comment: I'll try this in a few hours, but it looks good! In the meantime i've been using as key color the following: `new Color(125f, 33f, 129f, 1);`. Considering that I'm using a 1 in the alpha channel, I asume it's impossible to find a pixel with full transparency in a video file.

Comment: That will work too, there is no alpha channel in video.  Another alternative is to add another parameter indicating chromakey should be done or not and merge the two materials.  You probably don't want to use the alpha all the time since it making the shader do a lot of work for no need.