# Darken videos played on ARCore in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am currently working on an AR project which requires video playback when an image is scanned.

I was able to merge the `AugmentedImage` and `chromakeyvideo` samples from `sceneform-android-sdk` repository to render video successfully however I noticed the videos being played are noticeably high contrast.

I am using a custom `.mat` file provided from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722855/escape-chroma-key-color).

**Demo:**

[image: Original video screenshot]
[image: screenshot from device]

I tried subtracting from `alpha` on the `.mat` file however it didn't work.

Was I supposed to be messing with RGB part?

Some help please!

Answer (score 1):

> There are two issues touching your image darkening: **ColourSpace** and **Keying Quality**.

1. As I can see on the lower image the video isn't high contrast – it's in a wrong [ColourSpace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorSpace).

**Try to convert it to sRGB or to HDR10 or to DCI-P3** depending on your Android OS version and your `hardware`/`software`.

Read these two useful articles: [Android Color Management](https://www.androidcentral.com/everything-you-need-know-about-android-color-management) and [Android Oreo Color Gamuts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/77gm3r/android_oreo_color_gamuts_and_pixel_2_explained/).

[image]

[image]

2. Also, low-quality keying (alpha channel extraction) could potentially change the color and contrast of RGB. The following image shows how many holes might be in alpha channel (what spawns holes in RGB, because it's a premultiplied image – RGB * A).

[image]

You could extract low-quality alpha that made your image look bad. The following image shows high-quality (clean) extracted alpha channel (on the `LEFT`) vs low-quality (dirty) extracted alpha channel (on the `RIGHT`).

[image]

Comment: From my understanding on the custom `.mat` file, it shouldn't be extracting any color from the video - just render it as-is. Are you telling me it is still extracting color channel?

Comment: What do you mean saying `chromakeyvideo`?